# Liminf of sequence of sets $(A_n\cap B_n)$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Using the definition:

$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k$$

I did some set algebra (wich I'm not sure is right):
$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} (A_n\cap B_n) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} (A_k \cap B_k)$$
$$= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k \cap \bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} B_k \right) = \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k \right) \cap \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} B_k \right) = \liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n \cap \liminf_{n \to \infty} B_n$$

Are these steps right? I think they shouldn't be equal, but failed to find a counterexample. If this is wrong, what is the relation between them?

Comment: Why is it true that $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k \cap \bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} B_k \right) = \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k \right) \cap \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} B_k \right)?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conclusion is correct, but the steps aren’t. To see that the conclusion is correct, observe that $x\in\liminf_nS_n$ if and only if there is an $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x\in S_n$ whenever $n\ge m$.

Suppose, then, that $x\in\liminf_n(A_n\cap B_n)$, and let $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ be such that $x\in A_n\cap B_n$ for each $n\ge m$. Then in particular $x\in A_n$ for each $n\ge m$, so $x\in\liminf_nA_n$. Similarly, $x\in\liminf_nB_n$, so $x\in(\liminf_nA_n)\cap(\liminf_nB_n)$.

Conversely, if $x\in(\liminf_nA_n)\cap(\liminf_nB_n)$, then $x\in\liminf_nA_n$, and there is an $m_A\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x\in A_n$ whenever $n\ge m_A$. Similarly, there is an $m_B\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x\in B_n$ whenever $n\ge m_B$, and for $m=\max\{m_A,m_B\}$ we have $x\in A_n\cap B_n$ for each $n\ge m$. Thus, $x\in\liminf_n(A_n\cap B_n)$, and we have

$$\liminf_n(A_n\cap B_n)=(\liminf_nA_n)\cap\liminf_nB_n\;.$$

The problem with your computation is that it is not in general true that

$$\bigcup_{n\ge 1}(X_n\cap Y_n)=\left(\bigcup_{n\ge 1}X_n\right)\cap\bigcup_{n\ge 1}Y_n\;,\tag{1}$$

which is what you’re assuming in the step to which **Thomas Andrews** objected in the comments. For example, let $X_n=\{0\}$ for even $n$ and $\{1\}$ for odd $n$, while $Y_n=\{1\}$ for even $n$ and $\{0\}$ for odd $n$. Then $X_n\cap Y_n=\varnothing$ for each $n$, but $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}X_n=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}Y_n=\{0,1\}$, so that the righthand side of $(1)$ is $\{0,1\}\ne\varnothing$.